# Start Element <li> in <aura:if and end it outside the if

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-if

Here is my code

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.activeApplicationsList}" var="actApp" indexVar="itemNum">

    <aura:if isTrue="{!actApp.status == 'In Review'}">
        <li class="slds-item inReviewApplication applicationTile">                                  
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <li class="slds-item appliedApplication applicationTile">
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
    <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
            <h3 class="appName">
                {!actApp.name}
            </h3>
            <div>
                <p>{!actApp.id}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.appDate}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.location}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.payAmount}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.fte}</p>
                <p class="slds-float--right">{!actApp.status}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

The issue is that I can't write it this way because I get an error 
The element type `"li"` must be terminated by the matching end-tag `"</li>"`
what is the way I should be writing this?

Comment: not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, usually, the li tag is embeded within a parent ordered or unoerder list tag. additionally, your 'card', is it supposed to be a list item? can you add a bit more context and maybe elaborate on the end result you would like? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I left the other parts of the code out because they don't really apply.  There is a <ul> tag outside of the iteration.  The idea is that I want to display a bunch of items as cards but change some of the classes depending on conditions.  So if there status is In Review the card has a red border if it is in any other status it has a blue border.

Comment: Good stuff,  Mark's answer below should respond to your needs =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator in a condition expression in the class string and remove the `<aura:if />` tags altogether.

Documentation link: [Lightning Conditional Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm)

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.activeApplicationsList}" var="actApp" indexVar="itemNum">

    <li class="slds-item applicationTile {!actApp.status == 'In Review' ? 'inReviewApplication' : 'appliedApplication'}">
        <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
            <h3 class="appName">
                {!actApp.name}
            </h3>
            <div>
                <p>{!actApp.id}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.appDate}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.location}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.payAmount}</p>
                <p>{!actApp.fte}</p>
                <p class="slds-float--right">{!actApp.status}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: This almost worked.  I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place dumb moment I guess.  Here is what I ended up with
<li class="{!actApp.status == 'In Review' ? 'slds-item applicationTile inReviewApplication' : 'slds-item applicationTile appliedApplication'}">